# Disabling a lookup in a form

Tags: delphi, dataset, lookup

I have been given a form to amend which is populated from a dataset when it is loaded.
There is an ID field in the dataset which is displayed in one of the fields on the form. In instances where this ID field is missing I need to display a lookup in this field where the user
can select from a couple of reasons why it is missing, and if the ID is present I need to display it and not show the lookup.

I have been struggling to find the syntax that would enable me to do this, and any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify a bit your question: are we talking about a form that shows only 1 register? Or does it show multiple ones as in a grid? What do you mean by "display the lookup"? Do you need the lookupcombo (or whatever lookup component) to automatically display the possible values? Or do you only need it to become visible/enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understood the question properly

```
procedure TForm1.DataSourceDataChange(Sender: TObject; Field: TField);
begin
   if Field = MyFieldOfInterest then
     begin
        MyLookupComponent.visble := Field.IsNull;
        MyIDOnlyComponent.visble := not Field.IsNull; // or enabled ...
     end;
end;
```

Comment: +1, it is similar to what I was about to answer, but I understood from the question that the form shows only 1 register on loading the form and that the lookup (combo?) should be opened automatically.

Comment: That has worked many thanks, thanks to everybody who contributed to this and apologies for the lack of clarity in the question.